# Redirect blocked by CORS

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, cors

I am sending a redirect from POST API to adfs server in form of HttpServletResponse containing an URL with status 302, but it is giving the following error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load Resource A. Redirect from Resource A to
>   Resource B has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Where resource A is my api running on 'http://localhost:9000' and resource B is the adfs server.

I have access-control-allow-origin header in API set to '*' as well .

When I redirect from my api to Google using AngularJS it gets redirected successfully. Should I need to change .htaccess file in web or need a change in the API?

I have already checked

[How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work?rq=1)

[Redirect from A has been blocked by CORS policy. Origin B is therefore not allowed access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43816797/redirect-from-a-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-origin-b-is-therefore-not-allow)

[Understanding XMLHttpRequest over CORS (responseText)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400594/understanding-xmlhttprequest-over-cors-responsetext/13400954#13400954)

Comment: I think you need to allow Access Control Origin on your adfs server.
You can find out there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44905898/how-to-enable-cors-on-server-side-code-in-java

Comment: I have checked this. It is allowed on adfs server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

302 redirect is not possible in XHR request. This is how the browsers work. Instead of redirecting to that page, browser will call the returned url as API i.e another XHR request. You need to redirect using front end application passing back the redirect url.

Since, I was calling an api from angular and In response API was redirecting to adfs server with HTTP status 302. This will be blocked by CORS.

I solved this by sending redirect url to angular application as response of API instead of HTTP 302 redirect and then using

> $window.location.href=JSON.parse(result.data)   //result.data contain the redirect url from api

Answer (score 0):

The request is blocked by "adfs server" because unknown origin request. You should identify your machine, so the "adfs server" proxy allows you to make the call. (this is to prevent requests form unknown sources)